# How to prevent scroll resetting when Adapter data is updated

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am creating chat app and I want to refresh my data every second but problem is that recyclerview scroll reset their first position.How to get rid of this.Thanks in Advance :)

I used MySql sserver to add andd fetch data.

Comment: please edit the question and add what you have tried

Comment: what database are you you using?

Comment: I'm using mySql

Comment: why dont you use firebase?

Comment: It's my collage erp software. To collaborate with website of erp.That's why I used mySql Instead of firebas

Answer (score 0):

In the adapter constructor call [setHasStableIds](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#setHasStableIds(boolean)) with **true**.

Secondly, override the [getItemId](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#getItemId(int)) method in the adapter, making sure it returns a message unique identifier from your dataset (ie: cursor).

Make sure that each message always has a unique identifier which doesn't change even when refreshed.

Next some examples. Logically you need to keep the same Adapter instance all the time for the RecyclerView, and update only its underlying dataset (cursor) whenever it changes. The **updateData** method could be further optimized to make use of [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil), but that would be already a different question.

**Example Kotlin:**

```
class YourMessagesAdapter(private var messages: Cursor)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<YourMessageItemViewHolder>() {

    init {
        setHasStableIds(true)

        // ... rest of your initialization as usual
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return if (messages.moveToPosition(position)) {
            messages.getLong(YOUR_MESSAGE_COLUMN_ID_INDEX)
        } else RecyclerView.NO_ID
    }

    public fun updateData(newMessages: Cursor) {
        messages = newMessages
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    // .... rest of your code as usual
}
```

**Example Java:**

```
public final class YourMessagesAdapter
    extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourMessageItemViewHolder> {

    @NonNull
    private Cursor messages;

    public YourMessagesAdapter(@NonNull final Cursor initialMessages) {

        setHasStableIds(true);
        messages = initialMessages;

        // ... rest of your initialization as usual
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(final int position) {
        if (messages.moveToPosition(position))
            return messages.getLong(YOUR_MESSAGE_COLUMN_ID_INDEX);

        return RecyclerView.NO_ID;  
    }

    public void updateData(@NonNull final Cursor newMessages) {
        messages = newMessages;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    
    // .... rest of your code as usual
}
```

Comment: would you please give some example? Because I can't understand your answer

Comment: @erdharmik Added an example in both Kotlin and Java

Answer (score 0):

**Saving the current scroll position:** (Usually called in activity `onPause()`)

```
int positionIndex = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
View startView = recyclerView.getChildAt(0);
int topView = (startView == null) ? 0 : (startView.getTop() - rv.getPaddingTop());
```

**Restoring the scroll position after you have set adapter data:** (Called whenever you set/refresh your adapter data)

```
recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPositionWithOffset(positionIndex, topView);
```